# Percorrer HashMap com valores iguais

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicações em Java Web, onde contém vários CRUD's. Estou precisando realizar algumas validações de uns valores que armazenei num HashMap .Como faço para percorre-lo  e verificar se os values são iguais?

```
public Boolean validaProjetoAT(String itens) throws Exception{


        String [] ats = itens.split(",");
        AutorizacaoAtividade autorizacaoAtividade = null;

        for(int i=0; i< ats.length; i++){


            autorizacaoAtividade = new autorizacaoAtividade();
            autorizacaoAtividade.setCdautorizacaoAtividade(Integer.parseInt(ats[i]));
            autorizacaoAtividade = autorizacaoAtividadeService.getInstance().loadAtProcess(autorizacaoAtividade);

            List<ConfiguracaoCiclo> listConfiguracaoCiclo = configuracaoCicloService.findForTipoIteracaoForAT(autorizacaoAtividade);
            //ConfiguracaoCiclo configuracaoCicloAt = new ConfiguracaoCiclo();


            /*Buscar Projeto Asscociado a AT */
            if(listConfiguracaoCiclo != null){
                for (ConfiguracaoCiclo configuracaoCiclo : listConfiguracaoCiclo) {
                    if(configuracaoCiclo.getListaConfiguracaoCicloTipoiteracao() != null && !configuracaoCiclo.getListaConfiguracaoCicloTipoiteracao().isEmpty()){
                        for(ConfiguracaoCicloTipoiteracao ccti : configuracaoCiclo.getListaConfiguracaoCicloTipoiteracao()){
                            if(ccti.getTipoiteracao().equals(autorizacaoAtividade.getTipoiteracao())){
                                mapaProjectAt.put(autorizacaoAtividade, configuracaoCiclo.getProjeto());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                            mapaProjectAt.put(autorizacaoAtividade, configuracaoCiclo.getProjeto());

                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hashmap nao permite valores iguais. Adiciona seu código ai editando a pergunta, fica mais facil entender o problema com ele.

Comment: @Articuno na verdade, HashMap não permite chaves iguais.

Answer (score 5):

Existem [diversas formas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677256/java-8-streams-to-find-the-duplicate-elements), uma delas sendo:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "a");
map.put("2", "b");
map.put("3", "c");
map.put("4", "d");
map.put("5", "a");


Set<String> unicos = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> duplicados = map.values()
    .stream()
    .filter(n -> !unicos.add(n))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(unicos);
// Printa [a, b, c, d]

System.out.println(duplicados);
// Printa [a]

if(!duplicados.isEmpty()) {
  // Faz algo se existirem duplicados
}
```

Ou, sem streams:

```
Set<String> unicos = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> duplicados = new HashSet<>();
for(String valor : map.values()) {
  if(!unicos.add(valor)) {
    duplicados.add(valor);
  }
}
```

Comment: Projeto que estou fazendo faz uso do Java 5,devido Framework,essas formas que você sugeriu e compatível.

Comment: @RafaelLuz adicionei exemplo sem streams